# How to find neighbor vertex with a property value in graph_tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have a graph with some vertex and edges. I want to find which neighbors of a given vertex match a property value. I can do that with `find_vertex(g, prop, match)`, but this would search in all the graph. Instead, I have `neighbors = g.vertex(N).out_neighbors()`, and I would like to get the vertex that have a property value, something like `find_vertex(neighbors, prop, match)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
neighbors = g.vertex(N).out_neighbors()
[neigh for neigh in neighbors if g.vp[prop][neigh] == match]
```

Comment: I'm looking for a really fast way of doing this